# Spawn prefabs as childs of a game object in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I have a spawner game object which spawns 2 different prefabs.
I'm trying to make this spawned objects childs of the spawner game object but it does not work.

this is my try (this code is in the spawner game object):

```
void Update () {

    if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
    {
        whatToSpawn = Random.Range(1, 3);
        Debug.Log(whatToSpawn);

        switch(whatToSpawn) {
        case 1:
                Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                cube.transform.parent = transform;
                break;
        case 2:
            Instantiate(circle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            circle.transform.parent = transform;
            break;
        }

        nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
    }
}
```

and this brings me this error:

```
setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to set the parents of the cube and circle prefabs, instead of the actual cube and circle objects you are instantiating. Replace your switch statement with the following:

```
switch(whatToSpawn)
{
    case 1:
        GameObject myCube = (GameObject)Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        myCube.transform.parent = transform;
        break;
    case 2:
        GameObject myCircle = (GameObject)Instantiate(circle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        myCircle.transform.parent = transform;
        break;
}
```

Casting the `Instantiate` function as a `(GameObject)` returns a reference to the object you just instantiated.

**Note**: As Draco18s mentioned, it is more efficient to overload `Instantiate` with the parent directly, as seen below:

```
switch(whatToSpawn)
{
    case 1:
        Instantiate(cube, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
        break;
    case 2:
        Instantiate(circle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Great! It worked, but now it shows me a warning that says "Warning: BoxColliders does not support negative scale or size"

Comment: @Arthurfriednman Glad it worked!. The BoxCollider issue seems unrelated. It is probably best to open a new question and provide information regarding your gameobjects that have box colliders attached. Perhaps the spawner object you attached your cubes and circles to has a negative scale?

Comment: Note also that one of the [optional parameters of `Instantiate` is a parent transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) and avoids Unity having to recalculate the object hierarchy a second time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Draco18s. I was unaware of that overload.

Comment: No problem! Its something I only started using after watching one of Unity's talks on Youtube about performance. Transform hierarchies are fixed size arrays in memory, allowing Unity to iterate over them quickly, so insertion and removal can be costly. Not a lot costly, but may as well avoid it when we can, right?